# Firebase Admin : How to promisify a push operation

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, es6-promise

I have a function as follows.

```
const notify = function (uid, ..., senderId) {
    var obj = {
        "time": +new Date(),
        ... ...
        "uid": senderId,
    }
    dbRef("../notifications/").push(obj);
}
```

I call this from within other functions to write notifications, this is called among other functions that return promises, which are put into an array to wait for all promises to be fulfilled.

So I'd like this to return a promise instead of using a complete callback, you know, like how `db.set()` does.

**WHY I"M NOT USING `db.set()`.**

structure.

```
users/{uid}/notifications/autoId/notificationObject.
```

`db.ref('users/{uid}/notifications').push(notificationObject)` will adhere to the above, while `set()` will do the following.

```
`users/{uid}/notifications/notificationObject`
```

Which will practically just replace the entire user notifications objects.

Comment: Cant you do `dbRef("../notifications/").push().set(obj)` instead?

Comment: @AndréKool I want the destination to have the auto-id, I'd have used set.

Comment: I dont really understand your comment. The option I mentioned does exactly the same as the code in your question. You can take a look at [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#section-push) for more info.

Comment: Ok, let me update the question to reflect why I'm not using `set()`.

Comment: @AndréKool see update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways to write a `push()` function like the one in your question:

```
dbRef("../notifications/").push(obj);
```

One of those options uses `set()` like this:

```
dbRef("../notifications/").push().set(obj);
```

What this does is actually the following:

```
//Generate the unique push key and get the reference
var key = dbRef("../notifications/").push();
//Save the data to the newly generated reference
key.set(obj);
```

All three code blocks in this answer do exactly the same thing. More information about these ways of saving can be found in [the Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#section-push).

Comment: Nice, that's neat man, I use this on Android, just didn't cross my mind in this context.